# Problems logging into SharePoint using Firefox - even when ntml is set

Tags: sharepoint, firefox, sharepoint-2010, authentication

I'm struggling to log in to SharePoint using FireFox. On entering the URL I get prompted with username and password, but when entering these the logon dialog keeps popping up and the page is not loaded.

The scenario is this: I have three web applications running. All of them have the same settings and runs on port 80.

```
Name                                    URL                     Port
intranetttest Currently Selected        http: //intranetttest/  80
MySite                                  http: //minside/        80
SharePoint - 80                         http: //sp/             80
SharePoint Central Administration v4    http: //sp:42424/       42424
```

In one out of three, I'm able to log in and browse the page. This one share the "base" URL with the central admin. The other two, I'm unable to log into using FireFox. IE and Opera works fine.

General settings, managed features, managed paths, service connections, auth providers, self-service site creations, user permissions, webpart security, user policy, anonymous policy and permission policy are all the same - as far as I can see.

I clearly seem to be missing something. Anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Is it possible you have a URL verification plugin or some other DNS setting in Firefox that it might be bypassing HOSTS, local DNS, NetBios, etc and using its own hierarchy?

Comment: An additional setting to ntlm auth URL should be changed.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm should be set to true.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm | user set | boolean | true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the hostnames pointing to 127.0.0.1?

Could you then try this:

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value. Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.1.2.

Also check if the alternate access mappings don't have a domain name added to the hostname.

If that does not help, please try this on the server:

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the sites that are on the local computer (one line per hostname), and then click OK.
Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.

(Source: http://spiderwool.blogspot.nl/2010/09/access-denied-host-header-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems.
You should check whether **Alternate Access Mappings** are correct and check the **site bindings** in IIS-Manager. Sometimes the first webapp gets all the requests by binding to *:80. So assure similar bindings for all webapps.

And on the client side: Did you configure Firefox to pass over OS-authentication for some sites and not for others?

HTH
Ben